# MIP SDK error: LoadLibrary failed for: [sdk_wrapper_dotnet.dll] using c#

Tags: c#, azure-information-protection

Following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/setup-configure-mip 
I have created Console App, add code. After running getting below error:
LoadLibrary failed for: [sdk_wrapper_dotnet.dll] at  MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File);

Please let me know what am I missing.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Actual error in output: Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in mip_dotnet_api.dll

Comment: Same problem here. Have you installed MIP sdk with NuGet?

Comment: Installed packages:  Install-Package Microsoft.InformationProtection.File
Install-Package Microsoft.InformationProtection.Policy
Install-Package Microsoft.InformationProtection.Protection
Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Comment: I experience the same problem. However, it works well on another VM. The same code, the same DLLs, the same OS.... I wonder if there is some prerequisite missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 `
//Step 1:
 internal static class UnsafeKernel32NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        internal static extern bool SetDllDirectory([In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpPathName);
    }
```

//Step 2: Set path to bins folder

var path = Path.Combine(
                                   Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath)).FullName,
                           Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "binsx64" : "binsx86");

//Step 3: Use custom UnsafeKernel32NativeMethods class to configure managed to unmanaged marshalling.

Utilities.UnsafeKernel32NativeMethods.SetDllDirectory(path);

//After doing above Steps below code is working in Web Application
MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File);

`

Answer (score 1):

The SDK dll-s are incompatible with your run configuration. Try changing the processor from "Any CPU" to "x64".

Comment: This trick is working for Console App, but when develop MIP in Web App getting same error and tried the above trick, but solution not even running. Getting below error: [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MipSdkWebAppDemo' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was to install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145. I guess MIP SDK has dependencies on it. I used 64-bit OS, so installing only vc_redist.x64.exe did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run it on IIS, be sure to run it on 64 bit mode.

There's an option in Visual Studio 2013 now to direct IIS Express (which is usually used for debug) to run in 64 bit mode.
It's at Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express…